# OSError: SavedModel file does not exist when Deployed through heroku

Tags: python, heroku, oserror

I receive the following error when trying to run the app through heroku"

[image: image or the error]

This the model

```
def load_model_and_predict(my_image, version):
    model = load_model("/workspace/project5Ver2/")

    # Returns the probability that the leaf contains mildew
    pred_proba = model.predict(my_image)[0, 0]

    target_map = {v: k for k, v in {'Healthy': 0, 'Mildew': 1}.items()}
    pred_class = target_map[pred_proba > 0.5]
    if pred_class == target_map[0]:
        pred_proba = 1 - pred_proba

    return pred_proba, pred_class
```

I made sure that there are no typos in my code, but I cannot think of anything else.

Here a link to my [repo](https://github.com/nikolmichaelidou/project5Ver2).

Comment: And why do you think that `/workspace/project5Ver2/` exists?  Have you coped it into place?

Comment: yes. before it was "/workspace/project5Ver2/ saved_model.ph" and i received the same run error when I run it through streamlit. so i changed it

Comment: Well, you almost certainly need to specify a model file, but just remember that Heroku runs on a separate computer, and you have to copy the files you need over there.  It can't read from your local computer.

Comment: oh ok. can you please explain how to do that? :)
I am still learning. I apologize

Comment: First, make it work on your local machine.  Then, you can figure out how to get files copied into heroku.